# Hard Disk Drive Ejected

Tags: 13.04, hard-drive, hardware, devices, eject

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 and I have ejected my hard disk drives.
now I cannot find them on my devices list 
could anyone please help?

Comment: You can't have ejected your boot drive (partition). If you had, you couldn't do ANYTHING. Linux won't let you. Assuminy you're using Ubuntu 12.04 or later with the Unity interface, what happens when you click on the `files` icon in the launch bar? What happens if you open a terminal and type `ls`?

Comment: Desktop    Downloads         Music     Public     Videos
Documents  examples.desktop  Pictures  Templates
 ...that is being displayed after tying ls

Comment: You ejected you hard disk driveS? Multiple disk drives? Did you do this while your computer was booted up?

Answer (score 0):

```
eject -t <device>
```

is probably what you are looking for

Comment: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: That's weird. Do you include angle-brackets in the command? Do NOT include them, they are there just to show you that <device> is something you must change according to the real device name.

Comment: I just Pasted This In The Terminal  eject -t <device>
Are There Any Changes To Be Made?